# Passing the string 'BIN' as a route parameter in .Net Framework 4.7.2 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an API method with the route attribute defined as `[Route("{code:regex([A-Za-z-])}")]` with a route prefix for the class of `[RoutePrefix("Api/v1/Entities")]` which works as expected for almost all cases, such as `GET https://api.whatever/Api/v1/Entities/ABC`.

However, if I pass the string 'BIN' as the route parameter such as `GET https://api.whatever/Api/v1/Entities/BIN`, the method returns 404 to the client without executing the code or triggering any breakpoints in the method.

This occurs when testing on my local machine and when the application is deployed to an Azure App Service (arguably, both using some version of IIS).  I have already set `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` in my Web.config as recommended for other similar issues but it has not resolved this issue.  Any potential code fixes for this or should I be making other changes to avoid needing to pass 'BIN' as a route parameter?  Thanks.

Comment: what about `^[A-Za-z-]+$` as the regex? That match the whole word wheres what you had would have matched on each letter. See also http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `BIN` from hiddenSegments.

[Microsoft Documentation on hiddenSegments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments/)

Under you IIS site, click on RequestFiltering. In the Request Filtering pane, click the Hidden Segments tab, and remove `bin`.

Comment: Just tested this on my local machine in IISExpress 10 and confirmed that it works.  I added `<remove segment="bin" />` to my applications web.config as per the docs at your link to override the server-side setting

Comment: Adding to my first comment for anyone else who finds it.  Naturally, the bin directory is hidden for a reason so I have also added a few file extensions under request filtering in my applications web.config to exclude the contents of the server's bin directory as per docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions/